# Using COM objects in a T4 template?

Tags: t4, sqldmo

I'm new to Visual Studio's T4 template engine, and I'm wondering how I can use COM objects to build templates. Specifically, SQL-DMO (to generate classes from stored procedures on a SQL 2000 server, SNO is not an option).

Have any of you guys done this? Any tips?

```
<#@ import namespace="SQLDMO" #>
```

is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SMO 2008 with SQL Server 2000 (download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=228DE03F-3B5A-428A-923F-58A033D316E1&displaylang=en)).

In order to use a COM object, you need to reference its primary interop assembly with use <#@ assembly #> directive first. If the assembly is not available, you can generate it with tlbimp.